# Updating array based on check and uncheck of checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code that pushes values into an array as the checkboxes are checked.

```
var complaintIds = [];

function select_tickets() {
 $(".take_tickets").css('display', 'block');
 var id = $(this).data("id");
 complaintIds.push(id);
}

$('body').on('click', '.select_ticket', select_tickets);
```

However I'm not able to remove values from the array if a checked checkbox is unchecked. In addition to that the same value is added once again.

Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong?

thanks.

Comment: .select_ticket is the class of the checkbox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var complaintIds = [];

function select_tickets(el) {
 $(".take_tickets").css('display', 'block');
 var id = $(el).data("id");
 if(el.checked){
   complaintIds.push(id);
 }else{
   complaintIds = $.grep(complaintIds, function(value) { return value !== id; });   // remove id from array if unchecked
 }
 console.log(complaintIds);
}

$('body').on('change', '.select_ticket', function(){select_tickets(this)});
```

**Demo**

```js
var complaintIds = [];
function select_tickets(el) {
 $(".take_tickets").css('display', 'block');
 var id = $(el).data("id");
 if(el.checked){
   complaintIds.push(id);
 }else{
   complaintIds = $.grep(complaintIds, function(value) { return value !== id; });   // remove id from array if unchecked
 }
 console.log(complaintIds);
}

$('body').on('change', '.select_ticket', function(){select_tickets(this)});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="select_ticket" data-id="id1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="select_ticket" data-id="id2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="select_ticket" data-id="id3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="select_ticket" data-id="id4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="select_ticket" data-id="id5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the job:

```
var complaintIds = [];


    $(document).on('change', '.select_ticket', function(){
        $(".take_tickets").css('display', 'block');
       var id = $(this).data("id");
       if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
          complaintIds.push(id);
        }
        else
        {
          new_list = complaintIds.filter(function(item){
            return item != id;
          });
                complaintIds = new_list;
        }
       console.log(complaintIds);
    });
```

fiddle to test it
https://jsfiddle.net/2L38x4u9/